# Can single point value for potential water-logging be calculated using soil particle size, organic matter and bulk density

Tags: groundwater, soil-science, soil-moisture

I am studying the recent paludification (e.g. mineral soil forests turning to peatlands) in a boreal regime. I have collected peat samples from the peat/mineral subsoil contact that have been 14C dated. I have also calculated the slope of the mineral subsoil; a well-known factor controlling the paludification rate (Loisel et al. 2013).

However, many studies state that the water logging due to mineral subsoil characteristics is a major cause for paludification but these studies fail to provide any meaningful way to quantify this. The basic principle is neat, for example areas with clay soils and a flat surface are likely to become water-logged.

In my study I have collected mineral samples alongside the peat samples that have been taken in transects of 3-4 points. The mineral soil has been collected from the same point location as the peat samples. So I have 3-4 point mineral samples for each transect that represent mineral subsoil for each transects. From these mineral soil samples I have particle size distribution, soil organic matter content (based on Loss-on-ignition) and bulk density.

My problem is that I would like to statistically test (possible with generalized linear mixed effect model) if there is any connection between the mineral subsoil characteristics (subsoil, slope, some other variables) and paludification rates but my sample size for paludification is rather small (<50) and thus including all subsoil variables (e.g. clay, silt and sand-%, OM, BD) is not feasible. My question is: Is there a single point value that can be calculated from the variables e.g. soil particle size distribution, organic matter and bulk density that would describe the possible soil water logging?

And if not, is there some other approach you would recommend.

Reference:
Quantifying landscape morphology in ﬂ uence on peatland lateral expansion using ground-penetrating radar (GPR) and peat core analysis. (2013) Loisel et al. doi:10.1002/jgrg.20029

Comment: It seems like permeability/infiltration rate of the mineral soil might be a single quantitative variable that would capture the effect of mineral soil quality on waterlogging? I don't suppose you would be able to measure it directly?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I only had just enough amount of mineral matter to laser diffraction analysis to acquire soil particle size distribution so I have to work with I have now.